# Как узнать uri веб камеры ?

Tags: android, videoview, java

Есть изображение с веб камеры http://www.geocam.ru/view/cam1617x2602_palace_square_webcam.html
мне необходимо узнать uri чтобы вставить в мое приложение с помощью VideView. Как это сделать?

Comment: а посмотреть в исходнике страницы?

    flowplayer(
        "player2", 
        "http://vpiter.com/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf",
     { 
            key: '#$42fd39186b7ee9e9fc3', 
            clip: { 
                url: "http://46.165.251.205:8083/hermitage/h264",
                scaling: 'fit' 
            } 
        }
    )

Comment: [Хотлинк](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA), кстати, не есть хорошо.